# How to find all partial solutions of a list recursively

Tags: python, recursion

I have a box with a maximum weight capacity. I am given a list of weights of the items that I am supposed to fit in the box. I need all solutions that get to, or as close as possible to, the maximum capacity. What I mean is that I should not be able to add another item to any of the partial solutions without going over the maximum capacity.

If I am given the following list of weights:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

If the maximum capacity is `9`, the solutions should be (I may have missed one, but you get the point):

```
[[4,3,2], [5,3,1], [5,4], [3,2,1], [4,2,1], [4,3,1], [5,3]]
```

Here's my recursive algorithm, I think I am getting close but I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
def findSubset(alist, maxim):
    if maxim <= 0:
        return [[]]
    if len(alist) == 0:
        return []
    alist2 = alist[1:]
    include = findSubset(alist2, maxim-alist[0])
    for s in include:
        s.append(alist[0])
    return include + findSubset(alist2, maxim)
```

Current output is:

```
[[4, 3, 2, 1], [5, 3, 2, 1], [5, 4, 2, 1], [5, 4, 3, 1], [5, 3, 1], [5, 4, 1], [4, 3, 2], [5, 3, 2], [5, 4, 2], [5, 4, 3], [5, 4]]
```

Comment: "I can't figure out how to fix it." - Any errors? Unexpected behavior?

Comment: @hlt yes, I get the wrong output, only some are correct

Comment: Also, you have a typo: `for s in inc` should probably be `for s in include`

Comment: @hlt yes you're right

Comment: does it have to be recursive or can you use functions such as `permutations`

Comment: @ThemanontheClaphamomnibus I need it to be recursive

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? What is the smallest input it doesn't work for? What is the output?

Comment: @Bolboa a) you should really mention the need for recursiveness in your question b) that's a stupid design approach c) that sounds like homework, and questions that are homework but don't mention they are homework should not be answered, imho, because that would inhibit you from actually learning

Comment: @MarcusMüller Homework questions of this kind should probably be answered, if the poster shows a legitimate effort (which he did) - as per [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266979/contrived-homework-questions). Doesn't mean you can't mention better solutions without recursion.

Comment: @hlt true; but I still stand by the basic principle that the information "hi, I need *help on my homework*" is necessary for proper human interaction; I don't want to be part of fraud.

Comment: @Bolboa Please excuse my audacity if this is *not* homework. At any rate, you are **legally obliged** to cite answers and comments given here with *author* and *URL* if using them (see ["legal", section 3](http://stackexchange.com/legal)).

Comment: @MarcusMüller it may be a stupid design, but this is my approach to it, and I posted this question on stack overflow because I really need help with this problem and have no where else to go. Moreover, its small function I want to implement to a much larger problem...

Comment: @Bolboa, so this is not homework?

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes I'm doing an assignment based on branch and bounding

Comment: @Bolboa regarding the "badness" of the approach: if your list is not this cute little <10 elements list, you'll very very quickly run into stack overflows, because Python has no way of reducing stack usage on recursions like this. So your approach might look and work elegantly in a functional language that actually has the features to allow infinitely deep tail recursion, but because python doesn't, this won't work for longer lists. *Unsuitability* is a K.O. criterion for algorithms, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is written using Haskell. As it seems that this is homework, there is no point giving you the complete answer.

We use three separate functions, the function `f` can be made recursive as it is just `map`

```
xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

perms [] = []
perms xs = xs : perms (tail xs)
```

All you need to know is that `:` means `cons` i.e `1:[2] = [1,2]`
In python, we could write it as:

```
def perms(xs):
    if xs:
        return [xs] + perms(xs[1:])
    else:
        return []
```

so `perms xs` is just `[[1,2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5],[4,5],[5]]`

```
takeWhileLessThan _ []     = []
takeWhileLessThan n (x:xs) =
  if n-x < 0 then [] else (x : takeWhileLessThan (n-x) xs)
```

and `takeWhileLessThan` uses recursion. It operates on a single list, keeping track of the current sum.

```
f n xs = map (takeWhileLessThan n) (perms xs)
> [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4],[4,5],[5]]
```

The final function maps the recursive function over the list of lists. If you then wanted all values and wanted it to be recursive, just write another function...

if you are allowed for loops, then this method would work well. The only recursion is the main function.

```
def f(n, xs, solutions):
    if xs:
        m = n
        ys = []
        for x in xs:
            if (m-x) < 0:
                break
            else:
                ys.append(x)
                m = m-x
        solutions.append(ys)
        return f(n, xs[1:], solutions)
    else:
        return solutions
```

which gives:

```
>>> f(9, [1,2,3,4,5], [])
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5]]
```

Comment: um, I'm a py2 person; is that valid python3?

Comment: code-only answers are somewhat discouraged around here

Comment: Nice explanation! Still not sure about language, though :)

Comment: thanks! I like this approach of handling homework, by the way :)

Comment: this is a lot easier done in functional programming I find, but I'll try my best to translate this I guess

Comment: The point is to see the patterns. Decompose the problem into smaller problems, solve them then put it together.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to iterate on all element of the list, while building a list of possible solutions

- if the element is < maxim, recurse on a sublist on following elements for `maxim - elt`, and for each element of the result, append the element to it and append all to the resulting list
- if the element is  == maxim, add the singleton list containing the element to the resulting list

Code is:

```
def findSubset(alist, maxim):
    res = []
    if maxim <= 0:
        return [[]]
    if len(alist) == 0:
        return []
    for i, elt in enumerate(alist):
        if elt < maxim:
            res.extend([ [elt] + l for l in findSubset(alist[i+1:], maxim-elt)])
        elif elt == maxim:
            res.append([elt])
    return res
```

It gives

```
>>> findSubset(lst, 9)
[[1, 3, 5], [2, 3, 4], [4, 5]]
```

Above code only gives exact solutions. In case where there are no exact solution, it should be extended to give best approaching solutions:

```
def findApproachSubset(alist, maxim):
    for i in range(maxim, 0, -1):
        res = findSubset(alist, i)
        if len(res) > 0:
            return res
    return []
```

For example:

```
>>> findSubset([1, 4, 5, 6], 8)
[]
>>> findApproachSubset([1, 4, 5, 6], 8)
[[1, 6]]
```

because here the best solution is for 7 instead of 8.

Comment: In my code, if I change `if maxim <= 0` to `if maxim == 0`, I get the same output as you for the first part, meaning my code works. The trouble is when searching for approaching solutions, could you explain that last part, I'm a little confused

Answer (score 0):

```
def recursive_function(current_node: int, nodes_left: list, maximum: int, trace: list) -> list:
    sum_so_far = sum(trace)
    if current_node is not None:
        trace.append(current_node)       
    else:
        current_node = 0
    if sum_so_far + current_node > maximum:
        # That means, that current trace is already to big 
        # no need to search further this path
        return False
    elif sum_so_far + current_node == maximum:
        # Bingo! The perfect set of nodes!
        # No need to look further this path
        return {tuple(sorted(trace))}
    else:
        # We still haven't reached maximum value
        # let's check if we can pack some more nodes to trace
        results = set()
        for node in nodes_left:
            nodes_copy = nodes_left.copy()
            nodes_copy.remove(node)
            traces = recursive_function(node, nodes_copy, maximum, trace.copy())
            if traces:
                # This path gave us some legitimate results, we collect them
                results.update(traces)
        if results:
            # At least one possible path gave us results, we pass them on
            return results
    # There was nothing left in nodes_left that we could add and not
    # cross the maximum limit. The path leading to this moment fits
    # our requirements.
    return {tuple(sorted(trace))}


def findSubset(alist, maxim) -> list:
    results = recursive_function(None, alist, maxim, [])
    return results
```

Why do I do this {tuple(sorted(trace))}? So I don't keep different permutations of same results in my memory.

Time cost: n!

Memory cost: n